# How can one extract text using PowerShell from zip files stored on dropbox?

Tags: regex, powershell, dropbox, extract

I have been asked by a client to extract text from pdf files stored in zip archives on dropbox. I want to know how (and whether it is possible) to access these files using PowerShell. (I've read about APIs you can use to access things on dropbox, but have no idea how this could integrate in a PowerShell script) I'd ideally like to avoid downloading them, as there are around 7000 of them. What I want is a script to read the content of these files online, in dropbox, and then to process the relevant data (text) into a spreadsheet.

**Just to reiterate - (i) Is it possible to access pdf files from Dropbox (and the text in them) which are stored in zip archives, and (ii) How can one go about this using PowerShell - what sort of script/instructions does one need to write**

Note: I am still finding my way around PowerShell, so it is hard for me to elaborate - however, as and when I become more familiar, I will happily update this post.

Comment: If you're going to mark me down, it would be nice if you could write me a helpful explanation. But obviously, it would be more helpful to obtain an answer to the above, or at least be pointed to a similar question.

Comment: Best guess would be you are asking _initially_ for a complete solution with no specific problem for us to help you with. SO is not a code writing service. You say that you only want a push in the right direction. That would be useful to possibly you alone and is not a good question long term for the community.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This question involves writing code - regex and PowerShell script, and the topic is not SO, it's data extraction. It is tricky for me to elaborate at the moment, as I'm still learning PowerShell, but I will happily do so, as and when I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

The only officially supported programmatic interface for Dropbox is the Dropbox API:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers

It does let you access file contents, e.g., using /files (GET):

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET

However, it doesn't offer any ability to interact with the contents of zip files remotely. (Dropbox just considers zip files as blobs of data like any other file.) That being the case, exactly what you want isn't possible, since you can't look inside the zip files without downloading them first. (Likewise, even if the PDF files weren't in zip files, the Dropbox API doesn't currently offer any ability to search the text in the PDF files remotely. You would still need to download them.)